# Where are the settings for @font-size-h1 in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am just starting to learn about Bootstrap.  But I am confused.  In the Less files I see things like: @font-size-h1

Can someone tell me where these are specified in the default implementation of Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined in the `variables.less` file

```
@font-size-h1:            floor((@font-size-base * 2.6)); // ~36px
```

Where:

```
@font-size-base:          14px;
```